# Automation Tasks for a game in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, automation, ui-automation

I was wondering if it's possible to create a script for automatization of tasks, especially 
in iphone games.

Games like Tiny Tower, Hay day, Enchant U, etc.

This is some of the game that I found on iphone that would be a good test for automation task.

If it's possible, can someone tell me where I can find a tutorial to do this? or even what 
program I should use to do it?

I'm curious if its possible to build up things like gold 
points, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UIAutomation:

http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/posts/2012/11/13/introduction-to-uiautomation-testing-on-ios-video-slides

http://blog.ideveloper.tv/automated-ui-testing-for-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there's iOS Switch Control that you can use to automate some movements, scan parts of the screen and things like that.

Here's [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201370) for it. There's also plenty of videos and tutorials on the web teaching how to use it in some games.